# WPF Scrolling Canvas While Moving the Children Causes a Stutter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using C# WPF to scroll a canvas in a Scroll Viewer, however I am also moving the children in the main canvas simultaneously. What results is an intermittent stuttering of the children UI elements that are moving around.

The only thing I can think of is that since the movement speed of the children and the movement speed of the main canvas are different it is causing WPF to try and render children movement (before and after) before the main canvas has a chance to scroll.

Any suggestions or solutions to resolve this stuttering?

Details:
I am using a continuous loop that attempts to redraw 60 times a second. <- Reason why I think the two are out of sync.

Structure:

- Scroll Viewer
- --Canvas
- ---(Children)Loaded XAML or Canvases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone was wondering, the issue was with the draw loop, so I simply moved the ScrollViewer changes into the draw loop and the stutter went away.